# FROM Statements and "matches" on multiple similar tables SQL

Tags: sql

There are quite a few similar questions, but I cannot seem to find what I am looking for. I am building a dataset via a SQL query in TOAD. Ultimately, I will be pulling from 4 different table to "match" all the data together. I know "match" is not the SQL term, but my knowledge of SQL and what I want to do is limited. I want to JOIN matching keys (LDKEY=TICKETUID, which works), then match/join PERSONID to an OWNER (and subsequently, get the FIRST and LAST names for the person) from the PERSON table, and eventually repeat for a person department which I do not have in here as I presume it will be very similar to Names.

So I have:

```sql
(SELECT  ld.CONTENTUID, ld.LDKEY, p.TICKETUID,  p.OWNER, p.OWNERGROUP, p.PLUSDETECTION,
                ld.LDOWNERTABLE, LOWER(ld.LDTEXT), ld.LDOWNERCOL, p.DESCRIPTION, pe.PERSONID, pe.FIRSTNAME, pe.LASTNAME
                FROM 
                    MAXIMO.LONGDESCRIPTION ld 
                INNER JOIN MAXIMO.PLUSCA p ON LDKEY = TICKETUID, 
                    MAXIMO.PERSON pe 
                INNER JOIN MAXIMO.PLUSCA ON (pe.PERSONID = MAXIMO.PLUSCA.OWNER)

WHERE (p.REPORTDATE > TO_DATE('06/01/2018 0:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) AND 
                (LDKEY != '804928982' AND LDKEY != '804928844') AND
                AND (p.LEVEL = 'A' OR p.LEVEL = 'B' OR p.LEVEL = 'C')
```

The first part of the FROM statement works by itself as:

```sql
FROM MAXIMO.LONGDESCRIPTION ld INNER JOIN MAXIMO.PLUSCA p ON LDKEY = TICKETUID
```

However, we I go to add in the PERSON table, things break. I have tried several things like:

```sql
MAXIMO.PERSON pe 
INNER JOIN MAXIMO.PLUSCA p ON (pe.PERSONID = p.OWNER)

Yields ambiguous column error on LEVELs further down. 


MAXIMO.PERSON pe 
INNER JOIN MAXIMO.PLUSCA p2 ON (pe.PERSONID = p2.OWNER)

Runs, but creates a MUCH larger dataset than expected and OWNER and PERSON do not seem to match

MAXIMO.PERSON pe 
INNER JOIN p ON (pe.PERSONID = p.OWNER)

Yields undefined
```

What am I do wrong here? How can I pull "FROM" multiple tables?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know, what you did is wrong.

- You should compose the `FROM` clause table-by-table, test after each step you take
- Make it as simple as possible; if you're connected as `maximo`, remove it from query, it doesn't help
- Use table aliases
- `inner join` is as good as just `join` (at least, in Oracle; which database do you use? TOAD stands for "Tool for Oracle Application Developers", btw).

What you currently have is (simplified)

```
FROM longdescription ld
JOIN plusca p ON ldkey       = ticketuid ,person pe
JOIN plusca   ON pe.personid = plusca.owner
```

The 2nd line is apparently wrong. What is that `,person pe` doing here? It is unknown which tables `ldkey` and `ticketuid` belong to (no table aliases, right?).

The 3rd line contains table `plusca`, just like the 2nd line. That's "allowed", it is called *self join*, but I'm not sure that's what you really want.

Therefore, start with

```
select *
from longdescription ld join plusca p on ld.key = p.ticketuid
```

If it is correct, add another table: `PERSON`:

```
select *
from longdescription ld join plusca p on ld.key = p.ticketuid
join person pe on pe.some_column = p.some_column (or maybe ld.some_column) --> ???
```

I can't write the 3rd line for you, I don't know which columns should be used to join `person` table to `longdescription` and/or `plusca`, but you should know. Once you write it, run the query, see if it returns correct result. Then move on, add other table(s) if needed.

Finally, the `where` clause: after everything is joined correctly, use it to further restrict resulting data set. Something like this:

```
where p.reportdate > date '2018-06-01'            --> date literal; time component is set to 00:00:00 anyway
  and ld.ldkey not in ('804928982', '804928844')  --> use IN; table alias?
  and p.level in ('A', 'B', 'C')                  --> use IN
```